# Excel VBA File save

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up an auto save function on an excel template so that the original template isnt over written.

```
Dim NameFile As String

'Gets the users username
UserName = Environ$("UserName")

'User is to input data type 
datat= Application.InputBox("Enter a Data Type", "Data Type")

    With Worksheets("Home")



    'Sets up auto filename with YearMonthDay - Username - Filename(From a specific Cell) - Data Type
    NameFile = Format(Date, "yyyymmd") & " - " & UserName & " - " & Range("A1") & " - " & datat & ".xlsm"
    End With
    'Sets up save location
    NameFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & NameFile, Filefilter:=" Excel (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

    If NameFile = False Then
    'Tell user with a caution that the file has not been saved

    MsgBox "File not saved", vbCritical, "Caution"

    Exit Sub

    Else
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NameFile

    MsgBox "File Saved"
    End If
```

When I dont save the file and click cancel i get the message box telling me that the file hasnt been save... which is what I want.

But when I do save the file with the given name I get a Run-Time error '13', Type Mismatch

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without knowing the background to your question, this might be a silly comment but ... since you're talking about a *template*, why can't you save it as a template (*.xlt) with password-protection (and possibly mark as read-only in the filesystem)?

Comment: You get this error while testing `If NameFile = False then`
NameFile being a string it can hardly be `True` or `False`.

I don't believe this code does what you want anyway.
Does Alan's suggestion suit you?

Comment: Both good points above.  Also you can put a Workbook_Beforesave  procedure in your workbook module to prevent it from being overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ***Dim*** *NameFile* as *Variant*

That way it can hold either a *Boolean* or a *String*.

Comment: Thank you friend, I didnt even consider a Variant. This worked perfect. Thank you again

Comment: @S.Smith  You are quite welcome...Thanks for the feedback!